# CSS background size on multiple background images

Tags: css, background, background-image, background-size

I need to get one of the images to `background-size:100%;` but keep the other two as auto. I'm unsure how you do this shorthand.

```
background: url(/assets/images/site/bg-hero-l.svg) left top no-repeat,
            url(/assets/images/site/bg-hero-r.svg) right top no-repeat,
            url(/assets/images/site/hero-banner.jpg) top no-repeat fixed;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background):

> The `<bg-size>` value may only be included immediately after `<position>`, separated with the `/` character, like this: `center/80%`.

So you need to do something like this depending on which of those backgrounds need the 100% size:

```
background: url(/assets/images/site/bg-hero-l.svg) left top no-repeat,
            url(/assets/images/site/bg-hero-r.svg) right top no-repeat,
            url(/assets/images/site/hero-banner.jpg) top/100% no-repeat fixed;
```